# ORA-00904: "LECTURE_6"."CW_ORDER"."B_ID": invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle Apex, I am getting below error message on SQL query.

Error Message:

Query cannot be parsed within the Builder. If you believe your query is syntactically correct, check the ''generic columns'' checkbox below the region source to proceed without parsing. ORA-00904: "LECTURE_6"."CW_ORDER"."B_ID": invalid identifier

My SQL Query:

```
SELECT 
   "CW_ORDER"."ORD_ID" "ORDER_ID",
   "CW_ORDER"."ORD_ID" "ORD_ID", 
   "CW_ORDER"."B_ID" "B_ID",
   "CW_ORDER"."EMP_ID" "EMP_ID", 
   "CW_ORDER"."FNAME" "FNAME", 
   "CW_ORDER"."LNAME" "LNAME", 
   "CW_ORDER"."ADDRESS" "ADDRESS", 
   "CW_ORDER"."PHONE" "PHONE", 
   "CW_ORDER"."TYPE" "TYPE", 
   "CW_ORDER"."ORDERDATE" "ORDERDATE", 
   "CW_ORDER"."DELIVERYDATE" "DELIVERYDATE", 
   "CW_ORDER"."PAYMENT" "PAYMENT", 
   "CW_ORDER"."REMARKS" "REMARKS",
   "CW_ORDER"."STATUS" "STATUS",
    "CW_ORDER"."FNAME" ||' '|| "CW_ORDER"."LNAME" "CUSTOMER NAME",
    (select location from CW_BRANCH  
     where CW_BRANCH.B_ID = "#OWNER#"."CW_ORDER".B_ID) "Location"

FROM "CW_ORDER" Order by ORD_ID DESC
```

I just want to display the location of branch on query report corresponding of same row of branch id (`B_ID`).

The problem is on `(select location from CW_BRANCH where CW_BRANCH.B_ID = "#OWNER#"."CW_ORDER".B_ID) "Location"`.

Comment: Invalid Identifier means your column B_ID does not exist in CW_BRANCH or CW_ORDER table. Check in your tables for the column B_ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this.

```
(select location from CW_BRANCH  
 where CW_BRANCH.B_ID = "CW_ORDER".B_ID) "Location"
```

Here, `"CW_ORDER".B_ID` is referring `CW_ORDER` in your from clause and hence the `OWNER` information is not required.

As you mentioned like `OWNER.*`, it was actually referring a table named `OWNER` in your `FROM` clause, and hence the error.